# Wordpress custom style sheet not loading

Tags: wordpress, customization

I have added following code in my theme functions.php

```
function my_loginlcustomization() {

wp_register_style('custom_loginstyle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/login/login-styles.css', __FILE__);
wp_enqueue_style('custom_loginstyle');
}
add_action('login_head', 'my_loginlcustomization');
```

Custom login page:

```
<?php
/*
 Template Name: Login

 */
 ?>

 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Login Form</title>

</head>

<body>


<?php wp_login_form(); ?>  
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body.login {
  /*background-image: url('images/example-image.jpg');*/
  background-color: #258960;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
}

.login label {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #555555;
}

.login input[type="text"]{
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-color:#dddddd;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
}

.login input[type="password"]{
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-color:#dddddd;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
}

.login .button-primary {
  width: 120px;
  float:right;
  background-color:#17a8e3 !important;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#17a8e3), to(#17a8e3));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #17a8e3, #17a8e3);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #17a8e3, #17a8e3);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #17a8e3, #17a8e3);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #17a8e3, #17a8e3);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #17a8e3 0%, #17a8e3 100%);
  color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #0d9ed9;
}

.login .button-primary:hover {
  background-color:#17a8e3 !important;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#17a8e3), to(#0d9ed9 ));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #17a8e3, #0d9ed9 );
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #17a8e3, #0d9ed9 );
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #17a8e3, #0d9ed9 );
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #17a8e3, #0d9ed9 );
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #0b436e 0%, #0d9ed9 100%);
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #0d9ed9;
}

.login .button-primary:active {
  background-color:#17a8e3 !important;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#0d9ed9), to(#17a8e3));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0d9ed9, #17a8e3);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0d9ed9, #17a8e3);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #0d9ed9, #17a8e3);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0d9ed9, #17a8e3);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #0d9ed9 0%, #17a8e3 100%);
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #0d9ed9;
}
```

But no effect on page.

Comment: use wp_head(); wp_footer(); code in template login